# No output after using requests and BeautifulSoup in PyCharm

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests, pycharm

I was trying to get some headlines from the newyorktimes website. I have 2 questions, 
question 1:
This is my code, but I gives me no output, does anyone know what I'd have to change?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.nytimes.com'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
a = soup.find_all(class_="balancedHeadline")
for story_heading in a:
    print(story_heading)
```

My second question:
As the HTML is not the same for all headlines (there's a different class for the big headlines and the smaller ones for example), how would I take all those different classes in my code and give me all of the headlines as output?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would suggest you to use `requests-html` instead of BeautifulSoup for its readability.
https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/

Answer (score 0):

[BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a robust parsing library.
But, unlike your browser, it does not evaluate javascript.
Elements with `balancedHeadline` class you were looking for are
not present in the download HTML document.
They get added in later when assets have downloaded
and javascript functions have run.
You won't be able to find such a class using your current technique.

The answer to your second question is in the docs.
A regex or a function would work, but you might find that
passing in a [list](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-list) is simpler for your application.

Comment: Ahh I see! So that balancedHeadline basically wasn't HTML but javascript, so therefore the 'HTML-reader' BeautifulSoup couldn't read it, if I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, close. A simple HTML document (say with `<p>` paragraphs) will populate the DOM directly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model . A fancier website, such as the Times, may start with a tiny amount of HTML that just loads JS, which loads more assets and populates the DOM from numerous URLs. You are interactively viewing the result of such DOM construction in your browser, after the page took a few seconds to load assets and render them. That is much more processing than your GET + parse app was attempting. A framework like Selenium or Cypress is needed for such fancy pages.